# Renaming keys in NSMutableDictionary

Tags: cocoa

Given an NSMutableDictionary *dict, is this a bad way to replace keys with a new name? Is there an easier way?

```
NSArray *originalField = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"oldkey", @"oldkey2", nil];

NSArray *replacedField = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"newkey", @"newkey2", nil];

for (int i=0; i<[originalField count]; ++i)
{
    if ([dict objectForKey:[originalField objectAtIndex:i]] != nil) {
        [dict setObject:[dict objectForKey:[originalField objectAtIndex:i]] forKey:[replacedField objectAtIndex:i]];
        [dict removeObjectForKey:[originalField objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Put it into a category for reusability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, that's pretty much it. In general, you'd use fast enumeration and/or NSEnumerator to walk the arrays instead of going index-by-index, but since you're walking two parallel arrays, indexes are the clearest way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

That's not a *bad* way per se, but you could certainly make it more elegant (and in my opinion, easier) by cleaning up the code a bit and eliminating a few redundant method calls. As **@Peter** suggested, fast enumeration (you can use it on Leopard+ or iPhone) would be much quicker and cleaner, and therefore generally preferable. Here's an example:

```
NSArray *originalField = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"oldkey", @"oldkey2", nil];
NSArray *replacedField = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"newkey", @"newkey2", nil];
id anObject;
NSEnumerator *replacementKeys = [replacedField objectEnumerator];
for (id originalKey in originalField) {
    if ((anObject = [dict objectForKey:originalKey]) != nil) {
        [dict removeObjectForKey:originalKey];
        [dict setObject:anObject forKey:[replacementKeys nextObject]];
    }
}
```

One note of warning: you'll want to make sure that the arrays `originalField` and `replacedField` are the same length. If the latter is shorter, you'll get an exception, either from `-[NSEnumerator nextObject]` or `-[NSArray objectAtIndex:]`. If the latter is longer, you may wonder why some of the replacement keys are never used. You could use an [NSAssert macro](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Assertions/) to verify that during debugging, and it will be disabled automatically in release builds.

Alternatively, if there is truly a one-to-one relationship between the keys, perhaps you could use a dictionary to map from old key to new key, and enumerate over the result of `-[NSDictionary allKeys]`.